# Drupal 7 custom menu rendering

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-navigation

I am new to druapl theme development.
Created hierarchical menu from drupal admin.
I want to render this menu in my page.tpl.php file.
I have used following code, But its not rendering submenus. Its not that its showing them as display none, But they are (sub menus)  not rendered at all.

```
$params = array(
  'links' => menu_navigation_links('menu-eschopper-main-menu'),
  'attributes' => array(
    'class'=> array('nav','navbar-nav','collapse', 'navbar-collapse'),
  ),
);
print theme('links', $params);
```

Answer (score 4):

I used to do it manually, to have a perfect control on the rendering. You can use `menu_tree_all_data()` to load your menu links, and use a foreach on it:

**template.php**

```
function render_menu_tree($menu_tree) {
    print '<ul>';
    foreach ($menu_tree as $link) {
        print '<li>';
        $link_path = '#';
        $link_title = $link['link']['link_title'];
        if($link['link']['link_path']) {
            $link_path = drupal_get_path_alias($link['link']['link_path']);
        }
        print '<a href="/' . $link_path . '">' . $link_title . '</a>';
        if(count($link['below']) > 0) {
            render_menu_tree($link['below']);
        }
        print '</li>';
    }
    print '</ul>';
}
```

**page.tpl.php**

```
$main_menu_tree = menu_tree_all_data('menu-name', null, 3);
render_menu_tree($main_menu_tree);
```

Use `menu_tree_all_data('menu-name')` instead if you don't want to use a depth limitation.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are using 'menu_navigation_links' only displays links for a single level. You would be better looking at either the menu block module (https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) or using functionality such as the example below:

```
/**
 * Get a menu tree from a given parent.
 *
 * @param string $path
 *   The path of the parent item. Defaults to the current path.
 * @param int $depth
 *   The depth from the menu to get. Defaults to 1.
 *
 * @return array
 *   A renderable menu tree.
 */
function _example_landing_get_menu($path = NULL, $depth = 1) {
  $parent = menu_link_get_preferred($path);
  if (!$parent) {
    return array();
  }

  $parameters = array(
    'active_trail' => array($parent['plid']),
    'only_active_trail' => FALSE,
    'min_depth' => $parent['depth'] + $depth,
    'max_depth' => $parent['depth'] + $depth,
    'conditions' => array('plid' => $parent['mlid']),
  );

  return menu_build_tree($parent['menu_name'], $parameters);
}
```

This function will return a menu tree starting at a given url for a given depth.

The following code will produce a sub menu, with the current page as a parent and show child items up to a depth of 2.

```
$menu = _example_landing_get_menu(NULL, 2);
print render($menu);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But both things not working for me, for drupal7 default theme.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at the 'menu block' module, unless you want to start writing custom code. If you want to implement this you really should create your own theme rather than using the core theme.

Comment: I am writing my own theme, Till this time i  have used, following theme hooks, like help given here http://dannyenglander.com/blog/theming-multi-level-responsive-menu-drupal-7 , But i didnt got clean and neat answer, I want  to fully override rendering of menus and subbmenus their wrappers and classes and ids , I want full control (Override)  over core menu rendering. i.e i want controll over each Ul, li, a tags in whole menu.